# Efficient File Sharing with Synology NAS

Tags: ftp, nas, file-sharing, synology

I am using a Synology DS213. Before I got a new router I could transfer files very quick over the windows explorer. After getting a new router nothing seems to work for me. - Over Windows Explorer I can go to the second level of subfolders afterwards it tries to load but never finishes. - Over Synology Cloud it does not update subfolders somehow - Over FTP I can copy smaller files up to 100KB but for bigger ones it does not work.

I looked in the router settings and tried enabling and disabling different things, but I need some guidance, what to look for, because I am not an expert, when it comes to network protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dchp settings changed. Check for irregularities in jumbo packet settings.

What does copying big files with ftp does not work? What error code do you get?

Comment: There is no error code, just the message (my translation in English): "Error occured while copying the file. The time limit was reached." The DCHP settings are probably different, but I don't know how they should be; my router is 192.168.1.254, the option "Enable DHCP Server" is choosen with start IP ..1.1. and end IP ..1.253, subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and leased time 4 hours

Comment: Do you experience problem when using the Synology web interface?

Comment: No. Over the browser there is no issues.

Comment: How about reinstalling DSM?

Comment: I had the problem with 4.2 then I updated to 5.x, same behaviour.

Comment: contact Synology support then at [link](http://www.synology.com/en-global/support/knowledge_base)